# Sorting in ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: gridview

Its Arun. This time I have a sorting issue in ASP.Net. For the first click, descending is working fine but on the second click ascending is not taken again. Its still in the descending order. I m using Tableadapter to display the gridview content. Please review the code and correct me where I ve missed.

```
    protected void gv1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string sdir = e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "DESC" : "ASC";
        DataView dv = new DataView(ds2.AllocationPending(ClientLoggedIn.Text));
        dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sdir;
        gv1.DataSource = dv;
        gv1.DataBind();
    }
```

Also please explain - Is there any other way to apply sorting without Dataview.

Thank you .

Comment: [GridView Amazing Link By Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228113(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution for this issue. The reason is e.SortDirection always returns Ascending. So I need to store the e.SortDirection in a ViewState and sort the dataview with that value. Updated coding follows:

```
    protected void gv1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string SortDirection = "DESC";
        if (ViewState["SortExpression"] != null)
        {
            if (ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString() == e.SortExpression)
            {
                ViewState["SortExpression"] = null;
                SortDirection = "ASC";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
        }

        DataView dv = new DataView(ds2.AllocationPending(ClientLoggedIn.Text));
        dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SortDirection;
        gv1.DataSource = dv;
        gv1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: I don't get for what e.SortDirection is used then... Microsoft actually says that it should change automatically, if you click the same column header twice...

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {      
        DataTable dtSortTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

        if (dtSortTable != null)
        {
            DataView dvSortedView = new DataView(dtSortTable);

            dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + "" + getSortDirectionString(e.SortDirection);

            GridView1.DataSource = dvSortedView;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

private string getSortDirectionString(SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        string newSortDirection = String.Empty;
        if(sortDirection== SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            newSortDirection = "DESC";
        }
        else
        {
            newSortDirection = "ASC";
        }
        return newSortDirection;
}
```

Try this code for sorting the gridview

Comment: I m not using the Radgrid. I m developing the ASP.Net Gridview. The above code is applicable to Radgrid only. So no use for me.

Comment: Thank you Chetan for the gridview code. But its the same code logic which I posted in my question. You called the Sortdirection as a separate function whereas I included in the same one. Also a small correction in your code - if(sortDirection== SortDirection.Ascending) then newSortDirection = "DESC"; Anyway its working fine for the first time but not the second time. Please look on that.

Comment: I have found the solution for this issue. The reason is e.SortDirection always returns Ascending. So I need to store the e.SortDirection in a ViewState and sort the dataview with that value. Updated coding follows:

Comment: string SortDirection = "DESC";
            if (ViewState["SortExpression"] != null)
            {
                if (ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString() == e.SortExpression)
                {
                    ViewState["SortExpression"] = null;
                    SortDirection = "ASC";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
            }